Barto and Sutton's Reinforcement Learning Exercise 3.11: Don't understand solution because of knowledge gaps
I'm going through Barto and Sutton's Reinforcement Learning book with only knowledge of high-school Pre-calc and previous programming experience. I've been able to go through Chapters 1 and 2 successfully skipping the occasional math heavy exercise (note that I did do all the programming exercises.) However, starting from Chapter 3, its gets a lot more math heavy, I can't just skip the math exercises. The specific exercise I'm having trouble with is 3.11.
I would love links to concise explanations or just explanations themselves to help with this exercise, and for the rest of the book.
Here is exercise 3.11:
If the current state is $S_t$, and actions are selected according to a stochastic
policy $\pi$, then what is the expectation of $R_{t+1}$ in terms of $\pi$ and the four-argument function p (3.2)?
Here is a solution I found here: https://github.com/habanoz/reinforcement-learning-an-introduction/blob/master/chapter03/exercises3.pdf
$$E_\pi[R_{t+1} | S_t = s] = \sum_a\pi(a|s)\sum_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a) * r$$
So to start, how would you go about actually finding this solution? I read the exercise and am just flabbergasted as to what to do to actually get this equation. Yknow, I get that p is completely describing probabilities of all the actions and states and that $\pi$ represents the policy, but how do you go from that to this solution?
For just syntax here's what I understand: I understand the "|" symbol, which is saying the probability of the left side, given the right. I understand basic summation syntax, and that $\sum_{s',r}$ is doing every pair of s' and r. But $\sum_a\pi(a|s)$ is right before $\sum_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a)$ is confusing; does that mean the sums are being multiplied or that each probability of every action is being 'put into' that four argument function?
Just to recap, I need help with building the 'intuition' to actually get the solution and with concrete syntax aswell.
Thank you so much in advance! And be gentle please, this is my first StackExchange question, and more complicated mathematics really.
Edit: After spending an hour or two trying to understand the two explanations given to me through googling, I've realized I need to sit down and specifically learn probability. Thank you to @Ziv for the book recommendation and for everybody else who responded to my post. If anybody else has recommendations for resources that would be just lovely :)

This is not a 'solution', it is a mathematical expression of simple facts. Given a policy $\pi$ and current state $s$ we select various actions $a$ with probability $\pi(a|s)$. Each action generates with probability $p(s',r|s,a)$ a new state $s'$ and reward $r$.

It might be worth reading an intro to probability before getting deeper into RL. It will help make the time you spend on RL more efficient, and it will help with lots of other mathy things you'll no doubt do in the future. Here's one intro book I like: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~harchol/Probability/book.html

@Ziv Yeah you're right. After banging my head against the wall for a couple hours trying to understand the answers through googling various resources, I should really be going through a book like that. Thanks for the book recommendation :). I'm gonna read that through and then come back to reinforcement learning.

This is just an exercise on conditional probability. You just have to observe that the reward is dependent on the action and the next state. You then use law of total expectation or the towering property, i.e., average over all possible action and the next state given the current state.
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}_\pi[R_{t+1} | S_t = s] & = \mathsf{E}_\pi[\mathsf{E}_{A_t,S_{t+1}|s}[R_{t+1} | A_t, S_{t+1},S_t = s]]\\
& = \mathsf{E}_\pi[\mathsf{E}_{A_t,S_{t+1}|s}[\sum_r r~ p(r|A_t, S_{t+1},S_t = s)]]\\
& = \mathsf{E}_\pi[\sum_{a,s'}p(a,s'|s)\sum_r r~ p(r|a, s', s)]\\
& = \mathsf{E}_\pi[\sum_{a,s',r}r~ \frac{p(a,s',s)}{p(s)} \frac{p(r,a,s',s)}{p(a,s',s)}]\\
& = \mathsf{E}_\pi[\sum_{a,s',r}r~ \frac{p(a,s)}{p(s)} \frac{p(r,a,s',s)}{p(a,s)}]\\
& = \mathsf{E}_\pi[\sum_{a,s',r}r~ p(a|s)~ p(s',r|a, s)]\\
&= \sum_a\pi(a|s)\sum_{s',r} r~p(s',r|s,a)~. 
\end{align}

This is not a 'solution', it is a mathematical expression of simple facts. Given a policy $\pi$ and current state $s$ we select various actions $a$ with probability $\pi(a|s)$. Each action generates with probability $p(s',r|s,a)$ a new state $s'$ and reward $r$. Sum over all actions, new states and rewards and you get the expected reward from the strategy.
Example: there are 4 slot machines; I have 4 dollars to play with. For each dollar I use in a slot machine I might get \$10 with probability $p_i$ or nothing. My policy $\pi$ is to put a dollar in each slot machine: $\pi(a|s)=\frac{1}{4}$. The current state $s$ is 'game has not started.'
Given $a=\text{ pull lever of slot machine #1}$, I move to state $s'=\text{"I win"}$ with probability $p_1$. The reward is $\$10 - \$1 = \$ 9$. I can also move to state $s'=\text{"I lose"}$ with probability $1-p_1$. If we repeat the same analysis for all other slot machines we get
$$
\text{Expected Reward}_\pi= \frac{1}{4}(p_1 \times \$9+(1-p_1) \times (-\$1))+
 \frac{1}{4}(p_2 \times \$9+(1-p_2) \times (-\$1))
+ \frac{1}{4}(p_3 \times \$9+(1-p_3) \times (-\$1))
+ + \frac{1}{4}(p_4 \times \$9+(1-p_4) \times (-\$1)) \\
=\frac{p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4}{4} \$10 - \$ 1
$$
If I know that slot machine #3 has the highest probability of paying 10 dollas then my policy will be $\pi'(\text{pull lever of slot machine #3})=1$ and
$$
\text{Expected Reward}_{\pi'}=p_3 \$10 - \$1 > \text{Expected Reward}_\pi
$$

I think it can go like this:
$E(R_{t+1} | S_t = s) = \sum\limits_{r} r * p(r | S_t = s)$ (definition of expected value)
Let's have a look at $p(r | S_t = s)$ alone:
$p(r | S_t = s) = \sum\limits_{a} p(r, a_t = a | S_t =s) $ (summing over joint probabilities gives you marginal probability)
$= \sum\limits_{a} p(r | a_t=a, S_t=s)* p(a_t=a| S_t=s)$ (joint=condition*margin)
$= \sum\limits_{a} (\sum\limits_{s'}p(r, s' | a_t=a, S_t=s))* p(a_t=a| S_t=s)$ (summing over joint probabilities gives you marginal probability)
Plugging this in the first equation you have:
$E(R_{t+1} | S_t=s) = \sum\limits_{r} r \sum\limits_{a} (\sum\limits_{s'}p(r, s' | a_t=a, S_t=s)) p(a_t=a| S_t=s)$
$=\sum\limits_{r} r \sum\limits_{a} (\sum\limits_{s'}p(r, s' | a, s)) \pi(a|s)$
